# How to get attributes of relations through query in Strapi

Tags: database, strapi, querying

I am using Strapi's entity service to get data for all attributes including the relations attributes till the deepest relation.

But following is providing me the data of only one level deep relation's attributes. How can I get all the deepest relations attributes?

```
const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany(api::name.name, {
            populate: '*'
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the deepest level of population, you have to write out each element. There are community solutions out there that work just with the '*', but they don't work reliably for me.

But you can try them out anyways if you want to: https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-populate-deep

Comment: Thanks for that. For example if a content type has relation in it and that relation has component and a relation in it. Then how query will look like?